# How is it possible to achieve this functionality?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to control two units 0-10V control inputs simultaneously and inverted way.
For instance if the unit1 input is 5V the unit2 output will be OFF(zero V) and vice versa.

I could do this with using a comparator and its inverting input but there is one more condition I need to achieve. I want to set the outputs to a same voltage value as well.

Basically I want to simultaneously set both units outputs by a potentiometer(any voltage between zero to 10V) but still their outputs will remain inverted(when uni1 is ON unit2 is OFF vice versa). How can this be achieved in a way without using microcontroller?

**EDIT:**

I hope this makes more clear:

[image]

-When FunGen is ON unit1 must be ON and unit2 must be OFF

-When FunGen is OFF unit2 must be ON and unit1 must be OFF

-An interface(like I draw with dashed rectangle) must adjust the voltages to unit1 and unit2 same value when any of them receives voltage). The voltage value must be able to  be set from zero to 10V.

Precision is not important down to 5% is fine for me and zero volt can be 0.2V.

Edit 2:

Related to an answer:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: What should the value of unit 2 be when unit 1 is 0.1V? 0.001V? 0.9V? 0.999V? When you say "output zero" what is the actual maximum allowable voltage? Is there ever a situation where unit2 is something other than zero or 8V? What do you mean by "analogue way"? Is it OK to use comparators and op amps?

Comment: You are right sorry, precision is not that important 5% between outputs is fine and zero can be 0.2V something .

Comment: You didn't write how input1 relates to output1... only that output2 should be 0.

Comment: Alright I will make a drawing

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes I meant opamps transistors resistors caps ect.

Comment: I made an edit hope more clear now.

Comment: One pot and a DPDT CMOS switch. Your FunGen selects both switches. You get the inversion by connecting the pot to input A on one switch and input B on the other (grounding the other inputs)

Comment: @BrianDrummond What is A and B?

Comment: Each half of a DPDT switch has 2 inputs. A and B are common names for them.

Comment: I voted to close this question until the OP can clarify this into something that makes sense. The OP keeps talking about ON and OFF states which means digital and yet demands some analog 0 to 10V setting. As it stands now it is unanswerable and the actual goal is elusive.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Okay that leads confusion you are right. I had meant not use microcontroller basically. I will delete that analogue word from the question.

Comment: I made a circuit regarding an answer what do you think? Please see Edit 2.

Comment: The circuit makes no sense to me. One transistor is an inverting amplifier with massive gain and the other is an emitter follower with gain of 1. If you don't know what you require in terms of a circuit then don't confuse things by posting a circuit that makes little sense. Write down what you need in terms of requirements or a formula.

Comment: @Andyaka I am hurrying and made nonsense sorry. This works at least in simulation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUmve.png Resistor values might be not fine :(

Comment: I thought you needed an analogue control not purely digital?

Comment: @Andyaka What I had meant was not using digital components. I thought opamp and BJT are analog components so I corrected that in my answer already. By analogue I meant not using any sort of microcontroller in comments,

Comment: @Transistor FunGen is 0--5V on off control it doesn't vary from zero to 10 like in your graph. FunGen controls the output "states" not the amplitudes, the output amplitudes are controlled by the pot.

Comment: Then why are we calling it a function generator? Just call it the digital control input. There is no pot in any of your schematics. I've changed the labels on the graphs to "potentiometer". I've added a control table for you to edit. Please try and include all required control conditions in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the edit looks better now. R4 R5 mimics a 1k pot. I wont edit this anymore people are irritated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you were asking was as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOuNf3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A design for the analog selector is required.*

*Table 1. Control strategy.*

```
5 V Control      OUT1                    OUT2
===========      ======================  ======================
  0 V            0 V                     Potentiometer voltage
  5 V            Potentiometer voltage   0 V
```

[image]

*Figure 2. Your solution.*

The solution which you worked out yourself shows that you understand the electronics. The problem was only with defining it.

Hopefully this will help you formulate future questions more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Select an open drain inverter, and if you can't get an open drain input source, run it through an open drain buffer.  Buffer your potentiometer through an op amp or emitter follower, and run your pullups to that voltage.  If you have a dual gang potentiometer, you can use each wiper as a pullup.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUmve.png  Would this be something close to you mentioned?

Comment: That's exactly it.